# FTP Server and multiple clients between computers

Tags: java, ftp

I  have an assigment to to a functional FTP server and client that transfers files between clients. Problem is, what I try to run the Client on another computer, the Client doesn't connect at all, even if the Server is active on the first computer.

I have tried changing ports, giving IP address instead of localhost, deactivating the firewall, but it still refuses to connect to the Client.

The error code is the following : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

What's more confusing is that the whole process of uploading and downloading a file works perfectly on a single computer.

I repeat, I need to find a way to upload a file to the server and download it through the Client on another computer, or make the Server act as a link between the Client, and use multiple Clients to upload and download files between them.

Here is my code :

FTP Server

```
//FtpServer.java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class FtpServer
{
     public static void main(String [] args)
     {
          int i=1;

System.out.println("******************************************************
**************************");
          System.out.println("******************************   FTP 
SERVER
***********************************");

System.out.println("******************************************************
**************************");
          System.out.println("Server Started...");
          System.out.println("Waiting for connections...");
          System.out.println("
");
          try
          {

               ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(100);
               for(;;)
               {
                    Socket incoming = s.accept();
                    System.out.println("New Client Connected with id " 
+ i
+" from "+incoming.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"..." );
                    Thread t = new ThreadedServer(incoming,i);
                    i++;
                    t.start();
               }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
               System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          }
     }
}

class ThreadedServer extends Thread
{
     int n;
     String c,fn,fc;
     String filenm;
     Socket incoming;
     int counter;
     String dirn="c:/FTP SERVER DIRECTORY";
     public ThreadedServer(Socket i,int c)
     {
          incoming=i;
          counter=c;
     }

     public void run()
     {
          try
          {

               BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(incoming.getInputStream()));
               PrintWriter out = new
PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(), true);
               OutputStream output=incoming.getOutputStream();
               fn=in.readLine();
               c=fn.substring(0,1);

               if(c.equals("#"))
               {
               n=fn.lastIndexOf("#");
               filenm=fn.substring(1,n);
               FileInputStream fis=null;
               boolean filexists=true;
               System.out.println("Request to download file "+filenm+"
recieved from "+incoming.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"...");
               try
                 {
                  fis=new FileInputStream(filenm);
                 }
               catch(FileNotFoundException exc)
                 {
                  filexists=false;
                  System.out.println("FileNotFoundException:
"+exc.getMessage());
                 }
                if(filexists)
                {
                 sendBytes(fis, output) ;
         fis.close();
                }
               }
              else
                 {
                  try
                  {
                  boolean done=true;
                  System.out.println("Request to upload file " +fn+"
recieved from "+incoming.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"...");

                  File dir=new File(dirn);
                  if(!dir.exists())
                  {
                   dir.mkdir();
                  }
                  else
                  {}
                    File f=new File(dir,fn);
                    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
                    DataOutputStream dops=new DataOutputStream(fos);

                   while(done)
                   {
                    fc=in.readLine();
                    if(fc==null)
                    {
                     done=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     dops.writeChars(fc);
                    // System.out.println(fc);

                    }
                 }
                 fos.close();
                 }
                 catch(Exception ecc)
                 {
                  System.out.println(ecc.getMessage());
                 }
                }
               incoming.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
               System.out.println("Error: " + e);
          }
     }
     private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream f,OutputStream op)
throws Exception
     {
      byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
      int bytes=0;

      while((bytes=f.read(buffer))!=-1)
      {
       op.write(buffer,0,bytes);
      }
     }
}
```

And here is the FTPClient

```
    //FtpClient.java

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
class FtpClient extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 String fn,filenm;
 String fc;
 String dirn="c:/FTP CLIENT DIRECTORY";
 JPanel pnl;
 JLabel lbltle,lblud;
 Font fnt;
 JTextField txtfn;
 JButton btnu,btnd;
 Socket s;
 InputStreamReader in;
 OutputStream out;
 BufferedReader br;
 PrintWriter pw;
 public FtpClient()
 {
  super("FTP CLIENT");

  pnl=new JPanel(null);

  fnt=new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,25);

  lbltle=new JLabel("FTP CLIENT");
  lbltle.setFont(fnt);
  lbltle.setBounds(225,35,200,30);
  pnl.add(lbltle);

  lblud=new JLabel("ENTER  FILE-NAME :");
  lblud.setBounds(100,100,150,35);
  pnl.add(lblud);

  txtfn=new JTextField();
  txtfn.setBounds(300,100,200,25);
  pnl.add(txtfn);

  btnu=new JButton("UPLOAD");
  btnu.setBounds(150,200,120,35);
  pnl.add(btnu);


  btnd=new JButton("DOWNLOAD");
  btnd.setBounds(320,200,120,35);

  pnl.add(btnd);

  btnu.addActionListener(this);
  btnd.addActionListener(this);
  getContentPane().add(pnl);

  try
  {
  s=new Socket("localhost",100);
  br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
  pw=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
  out=s.getOutputStream();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.out.println("ExCEPTION :"+e.getMessage());
  }
 }
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  if(e.getSource()==btnu)
  {
   try
   {
   filenm=txtfn.getText();
   pw.println(filenm);
   FileInputStream  fis=new FileInputStream(filenm);
   byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
   int bytes=0;

   while((bytes=fis.read(buffer))!=-1)
   {
    out.write(buffer,0,bytes);
   }
   fis.close();
  }
  catch(Exception exx)
  {
   System.out.println(exx.getMessage());
  }
  }

  if(e.getSource()==btnd)
  {
   try
   {
   File dir=new File(dirn);
   if(!dir.exists())
   {
    dir.mkdir();
   }
   else{}
   boolean done=true;
   filenm=txtfn.getText();
   fn=new String("#"+filenm+"#");
   //System.out.println(filenm);
   pw.println(fn);
   File f=new File(dir,filenm);
   FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f);
   DataOutputStream dops=new DataOutputStream(fos);
   while(done)
   {
     fc=br.readLine();
     if(fc==null)
     {
     done=false;
     }
    else
        {
          dops.writeChars(fc);
       //  System.out.println(fc);

        }
    }
   fos.close();
  }

  catch(Exception exx)
  {}

  }
 }
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  FtpClient ftpc=new FtpClient();
  ftpc.setSize(600,300);
  ftpc.show();
 }
}
```

Side note : String dirn="c:/FTP CLIENT DIRECTORY" and String dirn="c:/FTP SERVER DIRECTORY" are meant for the places where the files upload ( Server ) and the other one where the file on the server downloads using the Client ( on another computer)

This is my first time working with networking code and I would like an corrected version my code, I have no idea where I did wrong.

Comment: Since you're using port 100, start the server program, then run this command: `netstat -ano | findstr :100`. What is the output? *(Edit question and add output)* Also, from the client computer, can you `ping` the server computer?

Comment: @Andreas Started the server, added the "netstat -ano | findstr :100" command in the Output window and nothing happened" Also, the client computer is my home computer ( I wrote my code on the laptop), if I ping it will give me the same IP address as my laptop? Or I'm pinging wrong

Comment: In the "output window"? You run that command in a different command prompt window, on the server computer where the server program is running. --- The client computer is you home laptop? Where is the server computer, then? At work, behind a corporate firewall? --- What is the client computers IP address? What is the server computers IP address? Are they even on the same subnet?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, let me be more clear. My laptop hosts the server while my PC tries to host the Client. Both are at my home. Both of them have the same IP address since I'm using a router with wireless connection between them. The code was made in NetBeans and I don't have the clue in using CMD in order to execute the command ( like what path do I need to set in order to execute it )

Comment: They can't have the same IP address!! They couldn't talk if they did. Anyway, your wireless router is likely not allowing a wireless device to talk to a wired PC for security reasons. --- No path needed to run `netstat`, just open a command prompt and run the command.